# I have built a shared library by Emscripten, now I want to transfer it into an shared library by LLVM.

Tags: shared-libraries, llvm, emscripten

I have built a shared library by Emscripten, now I want to transfer it into an shared library by LLVM. Can it come true? And how?
-e.g, I had compiled the xmllib2 by Emscripten emconfigure ./configure, emmake make. And it built a libxml2.so under ../.libs, now for some reason I want to transfer this .so file into a LLVM .so file. But I have no idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no shared library in LLVM. And only partly in Emscripten. So you should rather open your `libxml2.so` (with a binary editor), and see whether it starts with `BC`, meaning it is a [LLVM bitcode file](http://llvm.org/docs/BitCodeFormat.html).

If it does, you already have a LLVM static library and can use it like this in LLVM.